# Redirect to another route with data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have an route /account which is only accessible when logged-in. If an user isn't authenticated this happens:

```
 // Redirect to login if no custom access token found
 if (!customerAccessToken) return response.redirect('/'); // renders Home component
```

What i wan't is the redirect to send some information like `{ isLoggedIn: false }` to the home component. This way i can show a toast that says "Unauthrized access" for a few seconds. Is this achievable with **Shopify - Hydrogen**? Can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Where do you primarily handle authentication and manage tokens? Normally a backend would return a 401/403 response if the user no longer has a valid authorization if tokens have expired, the client can then prompt user to reauthenticate.

Comment: The problem is if i implement it at Home, it will show that everytime a person visits the page. It should only show it when redirected from an protected endpoint.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow what your comment means. Can you clarify what you mean? What I suggested isn't anything running on any specific page, but rather something handled in your API service code, i.e. the code handling the request made to the backend. Think of something like to a response interceptor that checks the response status.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that specifically, but u can render a client component that shows an error message like "Unauthencticated" access. Data can't be send when redirecting to other routes.

Comment: I am almost certain this isn't true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).